# Are there stuck/dead pixels in my photo?

Tags: canon, canon-6d, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

I have 9 months old Canon 6D. Please, are there stuck/dead pixels on this photo?

https://app.box.com/s/fw5lg0yrvejsv48ol6rm  (in the circle, where the arrow indicates)

I have it on all photos. I know, that coloured circle may be stuck pixels, but i have little white crosses too. Please, has anybody the same experience?

Comment: exact same location in all photos?

Comment: @rfusca yes in all photos in same location. I use only light from window, without flash or other light.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to clean the sensor recently? 2. If you put the lens cap on and make pictures (all black), do you have the same error at the same locations? (If you use Photoshop or Gimp thresholding, you can easily select all failing positions). 3. Crosses are RAW conversion artifacts most likely, most probably showing failing green sensors in the [Bayer pattern](http://www.mosaicarchive.com/category/raw-photos/).

Comment: If these are constant errors, you can easily use a workaround in Lightroom, or do some quick postprocessing in Photoshop. A few failing pixels is usually no big deal, it is annoying, but it is far less important than e.g. dust on the sensor or dirt on the lens.

Comment: @TFuto Yes, I've tried to clean the sensor now and took photo with lens cap on. It is now great, without any bad pixels. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Jana: Cool! This is great news! (I give it in an answer form then, too.)

Answer (score 6):

Try to clean the sensor, it may be that there are some dust particles sitting directly on it, creating parasitic capacitances near the pixel or blocking light and that is handled incorrectly in subsequent image conversion steps.